# Refreshing data in a workbook connected to SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I am trying to setup an automictic refresh "Every 60 mins" on a Excel Workbook, which is an extract from SharePoint. however the option on Refresh property is disabled, not sure why.

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAPBt.png

[enter image description here][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6j2a.png

Could anyone help please, I have searched on Forums but not got solution that works so far

Comment: Currently, I see that it's not disabled but just unchecked.

Comment: Thats a reference picture I picked online, as issue is on my work PC, that why I have mentioned saying "This is disable" apologies for confusion

Comment: What did you mean by "an extract from SharePoint."? How did you do that? Please provide your steps to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Do you have updates on this thread?